# Reset MAAS after loosing Juju configuration?

Tags: juju, maas

I managed to delete my Juju client cofiguration without running a `juju destroy-environment` first, leaving my MaaS in a state where I could not deploy to it.

I would get the following (conflicting) output

```
$ juju bootstrap
ERROR environment is already bootstrapped
$ juju status
ERROR Unable to connect to environment "".
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.

Error details:
no instances found
```

So, I tried running `juju destroy-environment` with the new config, to see if it would clean up the old Juju environment on the MaaS system. It gave me the error "ERROR gomaasapi: got error back from server: 409 CONFLICT".

I went into the MaaS GUI and stopped the leftover machines, and then deleted all the nodes and had then go through the discovery and commissioning stages again, but I still got the same errors after all that!

Is there a way to reset this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting/clearing/recommissioning nodes will not clear out old Juju settings. This is because MaaS stores files, some of them including the Juju bootstrapped state.

To reset this, you need to run:

```
maas-cli login root http://<your_MaaS_server_hostname>/MAAS/
maas-cli root files list
```

This will list the files that have been stored on the MaaS server by Juju. See if any of the files listed have the filename `bootstrap-verify` or `provider-state`. If so, run the following commands to remove the files and reset the MaaS to being in an "Non bootstrapped" state:

```
maas-cli root file delete bootstrap-verify
maas-cli root file delete provider-state
```

Run `juju status`. If it gives you an error that indicates it is not bootstrapped, simply run `juju bootstrap` and you should be good to go. If it gives some other error indicating that it thinks it's deployed but can't find a file or something, then remove the folder `~/.juju/environments/` (maybe back it up just in case), and then run `juju bootstrap`.

(See [the IRC logs where I found the solution](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2013/10/24/#maas.html).)

Comment: I get inavlid choice u'root' when running the above commands, maas-cli must have changed its input format.

Comment: IIRC, I think that the new format just means you can leave out `root` on the second command, as it lets you leave the username out once you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

in Ubuntu 14.04Lts with Openstack IceHouse I've resolved that removing the directory "enviroments" and "ssh" inside the path .juju/

```
rm .juju/environments
rm .juju/ssh
```

and re-launch the commands

```
$: juju sync-tools -e maas
$: juju bootstrap --upload-tools -e maas --debug
```