# How to reset MAAS 1.5 , LTS 14.04 Setting

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas

I've been experimenting with MAAS, following https://insights.ubuntu.com/2013/11/15/interested-in-maas-and-juju-heres-how-to-try-it-in-a-vm/, using 14.04. I must done something wrong, as I am not able to bootstrap MAAS environment. Here is the relevant portion of my environment.yaml:
   maas:
        type: maas

```
    # maas-server specifies the location of the MAAS server. It must
    # specify the base path.
    #
    maas-server: 'http://10.0.0.10/MAAS/'

    # maas-oauth holds the OAuth credentials from MAAS.
    #
    maas-oauth: 'xxxxx...xxxxxx'
    admin-secret: '123456'
    default-series: 'trusty'
```

The target node is in ready state, as indicated in MAAS web gui, and I am able to ssh to it, ssh ubuntu@10.0.0.31. However, bootstrap gets stuck during login to the target node:

```
2014-05-15 16:36:43 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:297 running juju-1.18.1-trusty-amd64 [gc]
2014-05-15 16:36:43 WARNING juju.cmd.juju common.go:40 ignoring environments.yaml: using bootstrap config in file "/home/navesta/.juju/environments/maas.jenv"
2014-05-15 16:36:43 DEBUG juju.environs open.go:86 ConfigForName found bootstrap config map[string]interface {}{"bootstrap-addresses-delay":10, "ca-cert":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICWTCCAcSgAwIBAgIBADALBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUwQjENMAsGA1UEChMEanVqdTEx\nMC8GA1UEAwwoanVqdS1nZW5lcmF0ZWQgQ0EgZm9yIGVudmlyb25tZW50ICJtYWF
...
2014-05-15 16:36:49 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environ.go:311 maas user data; 1315 bytes
2014-05-15 16:36:50 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environ.go:317 started instance "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-2ce27bec-dba9-11e3-940c-525400bba9bf/"
 - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-2ce27bec-dba9-11e3-940c-525400bba9bf/
2014-05-15 16:36:50 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap state.go:41 putting "provider-state" to bootstrap storage *maas.maasStorage
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to hbby7.maas:22
Attempting to connect to 10.0.0.31:22
2014-05-15 16:36:50 DEBUG juju.utils.ssh ssh_openssh.go:122 running: ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "PasswordAuthentication no" -i /home/navesta/.juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa -i /home/navesta/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@hbby7.maas /bin/bash
2014-05-15 16:36:50 DEBUG juju.utils.ssh ssh_openssh.go:122 running: ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "PasswordAuthentication no" -i /home/navesta/.juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa -i /home/navesta/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@10.0.0.31 /bin/bash
2014-05-15 16:36:55 DEBUG juju.utils.ssh ssh_openssh.go:122 running: ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "PasswordAuthentication no" -i /home/navesta/.juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa -i /home/navesta/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@hbby7.maas /bin/bash
```

Another symptom of my problem is that while my target node is in ready state, it will shut down upon restart. To avoid this problem, I have to put it in Allocated mode and restart it.
I have tried removing, re-commissioning and destroying the mass environment, to no avail.
(Also followed, [Reset MAAS after loosing Juju configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364821/reset-maas-after-loosing-juju-configuration/364823#364823), but APIs seems to have changed.)
Any hint or thought is appreciated.
Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you should have your nodes in the Ready state before attempting to use Juju with them. Make sure that all of your VMs are set to Network Boot and are switched off. MAAS will power them on when needed (i.e. when Juju wants to deploy something to them).

One issue that you might be encountering is that Juju can timeout attempting to SSH to the nodes. You can configure the length of the timeout in your environments.yaml file. See [Juju 1.18.0 release notes](https://launchpad.net/juju-core/+milestone/1.18.0) for further details.

Answer (score -1):

juju juju.utils.ssh ssh_openssh.go ignores .ssh/config and
$ ssh <...> /bin/bash
needs an extra option -o "RequestTTY yes"

Seems in upstream there is a double -t to "solve" the issue but my suggestion would be to use .ssh/config